# sshfs fails when not used with sudo

Tags: 22.04, fuse

I changed computers, and now I have trouble getting sshfs to work again.

Using the command `sshfs user@server:/home/user/ /mnt/server` fails with an:
*fusermount3: mount failed: Operation not permitted*.
When I run the command with a preceeding `sudo`, it works - but that's somewhat beside the point. This used to work without using sudo.

This used to work on my older machine, which was also running Ubuntu 22.04. However, it's been a while since I set the old machine up, so I guess I may have forgotten something.

The mount-directory /mnt/server belongs to my current user, both as owner and with the group.

---

Simply logging in using ssh works, i.e., using `ssh user@server`. So, what is the operation that is not permitted?

The mount-point looks as follows:

```
user@host:~$ ls -ld /mnt/server
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jän 16 17:30 /mnt/server
user@host:~$
```

---

Further info:

```
user@host:~$ type -a fusermount3 
fusermount3 ist /usr/bin/fusermount3
fusermount3 ist /bin/fusermount3
user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/fusermount3 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35200 Mär 23  2022 /usr/bin/fusermount3
```

I tried it on a different computer, also running Ubuntu-22.04, and I noticed some differences in the groups, that the local user is a member of:

```
user@host:~$ id
uid=1003(user) gid=1003(user) Gruppen=1003(user),27(sudo),46(plugdev)

user@otherHost:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) Gruppen=1000(user),4(adm),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)
```

With `host` being the computer, where it's not working; and `otherHost` being the other computer where it works.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of 'ls -ld /mnt/server' ...

Comment: Yes. The local-user and the server-user are both created by me. I have admin-access to both machines. The local machine is an Ubuntu-22.04 machine, the server is a CentOS-7 machine.

Comment: Please test what happens if you create a mount-directory in your home-folder mkdir ~/server and try to mount it there.. sshfs user@server:/home/user/ ~/server

Comment: The same: fusermount3: mount failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Please add the output of `type -a fusermount3; ls -l /usr/bin/fusermount3` to your question.

Comment: the set-user-ID bit is missing while it should be there for non-admin users to be able to use that command ... Run `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/fusermount3` to set that bit and then check if it works.

Comment: @Raffa That's it. Please formulate an answer from your comment, so that we can properly close the question. Thanks

Comment: @Raffa - thats brilliant. Please create an answer to get your reputation ;-)

Comment: @Eekiig Thanks, I get my happiness from interacting with this community like you and OP (helping and learning) and that is what really matters to me and holds real value regardless of reputation points  ... Your response words in your comments are worth all the reputation points of the world ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your:

> ```
> $ ls -l /usr/bin/fusermount3 
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35200 Mär 23  2022 /usr/bin/fusermount3
> ```

... is missing the set-user-ID bit while it should be there by default for non-admin users to be able to use that command for mounting a filesystem ... That bit when set will run the command as the owner user i.e. `root` regardless of the invoking user/process or else the command will run as the invoking user instead and you will need to either be `root` or use `sudo` as you have experienced.

Run:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/fusermount3
```

... to set that bit so it will look like this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/fusermount3 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35200 Mär 23  2022 /usr/bin/fusermount3
```

... and then try your command again and it should work.